# Sorting an Array that consists of numbers, BUT can include strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am facing an issue where I get results from API(mainly array of numbers), but if the devs make mistake and leave the field empty I will get empty string ("").
I am trying to sort this array in an ascending order and move the empty strings in the back of the Array, like that:

```
let arr = [3, 4, "", 1, 5, 2]   // Example Array from api
```

This array, when modified should become:

```
let res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ""]
```

I tried using the arr.sort() method, but the results look like that:

```
let res = ["",1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5]
```

For some reason when the element is string, the sort method puts it in the front, not in the end like it does with undefined or null for example.

Comment: Use list slicing to move all strings at the end?

Comment: Was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: I guess that processing will be faster if you keep the standard sort, then detect the strings and move them to the end (or just discard ?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1

```js
let arr = [3, 4, "", 1, 5, 2];
const res = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        return 1;
    } else if (typeof b === 'string') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return a - b;
    }
}
);

console.log(res)
```

Output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '' ]
```

### Method 2

```js
const res = (arr) => {
    let newArr = [];
    let strArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
            strArr.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr.concat(strArr);
}

console.log(res(arr));
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay bro, I was testing it, Method 1 was exactly what I wanted, because I wanted to connect it directly to a .map() method, thanks a lot!